# Image.prefetch not automatically loading from cache [React-Native / Expo]

Tags: image, caching, react-native, prefetch, expo

I am trying to understand how to cache an Image url so that it does not need to be redownloaded.
I have taken a look at: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets.html
and have been using Image.prefetch like so:

```
const prefetchedImages = images.map(url => {
  console.log('url', url) //this is correctly logging the url
  return Image.prefetch(url)
});

Promise.all(prefetchedImages)
    .then(() => {
        this.setState({loaded:true})
})
```

This ultimately does set the state as true. I am then rendering my Images in a different component, but I make sure the component that is prefetching does not unmount. I load the url like so:

```
<Image source={{uri: myImageUrl}} style={{width:100, height:100}} />
```

When I load images into my grid view, only the local images appear right away, and the ones with URLs are white for a moment before rendering. When using cache:‘force-cache’ on iOS, the images are in fact loaded from cache and there is no lag. I thought I did not need to do that if I used prefetch.

Am I missing something here? I thought I can call my Image source as usual and the system will know how to grab the cached image for that url.

Comment: You can try to implement this solution https://medium.com/one-more-thing-studio/caching-your-images-on-react-native-with-expo-7bff361dbd54

Comment: You cannot rely on prefetch in most cases. I wrote a medium story on that topic at https://medium.com/@wcandillon/5-things-to-know-about-images-react-native-69be41d2a9ee

Answer (score 1):

I do not think prefetch is quite as simple as just loading the image from cache just because it is in the cache, if that makes sense.

Check out this thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2314 and this question [React native Image prefetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314050/react-native-image-prefetch).

If you want to save images and have them always available offline look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-preload-images.